# error code -1407 Mac OS X 10.6.7

Tags: macos

Out of the blue, I can't send any files to the trash bin. "The operation can't be completed because an unexpected error occurred (error code -1407)

Any ideas for me?

Comment: Mac OS error -1407 (errFSNotAFolder): Expected a folder, got a file.
Try dragging a blank folder into the trash bin and see what happens

Comment: Try logging out then in again. I've had this happen to me once when a process took ownership of the ~/trash

Answer (score 2):

*Finder*’s trash can is an amalgam of several different directories:

- `~/.Trash/`
- `/.Trashes/<uid>/` on each volume (including the startup volume)
  e.g. `/Volumes/Big Media Volume/.Trashes/501/`

Most trash operations will move the trashed item to the directory under your home directory. If you trash something on an separate volume, however, *Finder* will move the item into the volume’s `/.Trashes/<uid>/` directory instead (because moving a file to a location on the same volume is very fast, but copying a file from some other volume to your home directory’s trash directory could be quite slow).

Try checking your main trash directory (in a *Terminal* window):

```
ls -ld ~/.Trash
```

If the result does not look like start with `drwx------` and show your user’s “short name” twice (the second is actually a group name), then your personal trash directory has probably been fouled. You can move it aside then logout and login again:

```
cd ~ && mv .Trash .Trash.old
# now logout and re-login
```

This should create a new `~/.Trash` directory for you. You may want to investigate the contents of the `.Trash.old` file/directory to try to determine its origin.

If the problem is with a per-volume trash directory, you should be able to use the same idea: move it aside, eject it, then remount it (disconnect and reconnect an external disk, reopen a disk image, use *Disk Utility* to remount an internal volume):

```
cd '/Volume/whereever' && mv .Trashes .Trashes.old
# then eject and remount
```

You may need `… && sudo mv …` if the volume has “Owners Enabled”.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try repairing file permissions with Disk Utility.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to reboot or reformat, just open a Terminal and delete files or folder with rm. Worked for me to delete an app from a USB key.

Comment: Why'd someone downvote this? I haven't tried this but it makes sense